# PHP Get total of every n elements in array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm working with an API that returns JSON akin to the array below. Each ID is in decimal as indicated. I need to print out each element of the ID.x (as per the whole number of the ID) and the marks for each, then the total afterwards. (e.g. output: 
ID 0.1 = 2 mks
 ID 0.2 = 4 mks
 ID 0.3 = 1 mks
**ID 0 total = 7**
ID 1.1 = ........).

```
<?php
$sampleArray = array(
  
    array("id"=>0.1, "marks"=>2),
    array("id"=>0.2, "marks"=>4),
    array("id"=>0.3, "marks"=>1),
    array("id"=>1.1, "marks"=>6),
    array("id"=>1.2, "marks"=>0),
    array("id"=>1.3, "marks"=>8),
    array("id"=>2.1, "marks"=>7),
    array("id"=>2.2, "marks"=>12),
);
 
$arrayLength = count($sampleArray);

$i = 0;
$x = 0;

while ($i < $arrayLength){
    $sum = 0;
 
    $idWhole = floor($sampleArray[$i]['id']);
    if(idWhole == $x){
        $sum += $sampleArray[$i]['marks'];
        echo 'id: '.$sampleArray['id'].', marks: '.$sampleArray[$i]['marks'].'<br>';
    }else{
        echo '<br>Sum of ID $idWhole is $sum<br>'; 
        $x++;
    }  
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: Just cast that ID value into an integer, and then implement a classic _control break_ on that …?

Comment: `idWhole` without `$` is a typo in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, you don't need to cast anything -- PHP will force your float values to be integers (truncate/floor the value) when you use them as keys in your output array.

Sum as you loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/e6o1Q))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($sampleArray as $row) {
    $result[$row['id']] = ($result[$row['id']] ?? 0) + $row['marks'];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 7,
  1 => 14,
  2 => 19,
)
```

---

From PHP7.3, you can use `array_key_last()` to make the conditional echoing easy.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aT4eU))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($sampleArray as $row) {
    if ($result && !isset($result[$row['id']])) {  // $result is not empty and current id is not yet in output array
        $lastKey = array_key_last($result);
        echo "Sum of ID $lastKey is {$result[$lastKey]}<br><br>";
    }
    echo "id: {$row['id']}, marks: {$row['marks']}<br>";
    $result[$row['id']] = ($result[$row['id']] ?? 0) + $row['marks'];
}
if ($result) {
    echo "Sum of ID {$row['id']} is {$result[$row['id']]}";
}
```

Output:

```
id: 0.1, marks: 2
id: 0.2, marks: 4
id: 0.3, marks: 1
Sum of ID 0 is 7

id: 1.1, marks: 6
id: 1.2, marks: 0
id: 1.8, marks: 8
Sum of ID 1 is 14

id: 2.1, marks: 7
id: 2.2, marks: 12
Sum of ID 2 is 19
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked great. I'm really grateful

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$txt = "PHP";
$sampleArray = array(
  array("id"=>0.1, "marks"=>2),
  array("id"=>0.2, "marks"=>4),
  array("id"=>0.3, "marks"=>1),
  array("id"=>1.1, "marks"=>6),
  array("id"=>1.2, "marks"=>0),
  array("id"=>1.3, "marks"=>8),
  array("id"=>2.1, "marks"=>7),
  array("id"=>2.2, "marks"=>12),
);

$total = 0;
$index = 0;
foreach($sampleArray as $item) {
    if($index == 0) { (int)$item['id']; }
    if((int)$item['id'] != $index){
        echo "<b>ID {$index} = {$total} mks</b></br>";
        $index = (int)$item['id'];
        $total = 0;
    }
    echo "ID {$item['id']} = {$item['marks']} mks</br>";
    $total += $item['marks']; 
}
echo "<b>ID {$index} = {$total} mks</b>";

?>
```

Output :

```
ID 0.1 = 2 mks
ID 0.2 = 4 mks
ID 0.3 = 1 mks
ID 0 = 7 mks
ID 1.1 = 6 mks
ID 1.2 = 0 mks
ID 1.3 = 8 mks
ID 1 = 14 mks
ID 2.1 = 7 mks
ID 2.2 = 12 mks
ID 2 = 19 mks
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.